# compile native hadoop3.0.0 failed: hadoop-common: make failed with error code 2

Tags: compiler-errors, hadoop3

I have installed all the neccessary software in BUILDING.txt.
I run `#mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipShade -e -Drequire.isal` 
It shows something below.

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................. SUCCESS [  1.142 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Build Tools .......................... SUCCESS [  1.017 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  0.871 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations .......................... SUCCESS [  0.446 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies ........................... SUCCESS [  0.161 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM ..................... SUCCESS [  0.872 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ........................ SUCCESS [  1.879 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC .............................. SUCCESS [  0.521 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................. SUCCESS [  2.634 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ........................ SUCCESS [  1.125 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... FAILURE [  4.802 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Client .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Native Client ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN API ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Common .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server Common ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Registry ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN NodeManager ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Web Proxy ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ApplicationHistoryService ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Timeline Service ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ResourceManager ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server Tests .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Client .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN SharedCacheManager .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Timeline Plugin Storage ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN TimelineService HBase Backend ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Timeline Service HBase tests .... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Router .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Applications .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN DistributedShell ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Unmanaged Am Launcher ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Site ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN UI .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Project ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Client ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Core ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Common ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Shuffle .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce App ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce HistoryServer .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce JobClient .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce HistoryServer Plugins ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce NativeTask ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Examples ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Streaming .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distributed Copy ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archives ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archive Logs ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Rumen ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Gridmix .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Data Join ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Extras ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Pipes ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop OpenStack support .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Amazon Web Services support .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Kafka Library support ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Azure support ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Aliyun OSS support ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client Aggregator .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Mini-Cluster ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Scheduler Load Simulator ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Resource Estimator Service ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Azure Data Lake support .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools Dist ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client API ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client Runtime ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client Packaging Invariants .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client Test Minicluster .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client Packaging Invariants for Test . SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client Packaging Integration Tests ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distribution ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client Modules ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Cloud Storage ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Cloud Storage Project ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.405 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-27T15:34:18Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 90M/770M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0:cmake-compile (cmake-compile) on project hadoop-common: make failed with error code 2 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0:cmake-compile (cmake-compile) on project hadoop-common: make failed with error code 2
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: make failed with error code 2
        at org.apache.hadoop.maven.plugin.cmakebuilder.CompileMojo.runMake(CompileMojo.java:229)
        at org.apache.hadoop.maven.plugin.cmakebuilder.CompileMojo.execute(CompileMojo.java:98)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-common
```

After googling, I thought the problem may exist in pom.xml. So I put the pom below:
https://github.com/chosen-ox/openec/blob/master/hdfs3-integration/src/pom.xml

Compiling non-native version might help. But I only want the native one.

Could someone fix the error

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The glibc version of ubuntu 22.04 is higher than the neccessary version. Installing lower version ubuntu works.